# Meta tags, existe para definir a imagem do site?

Tags: html5, html-meta-tag

Eu tenho uma dúvida, eu uso as meta tags para inserir a descrição do site, o autor, palavras chaves etc. Eu gostaria de saber, existe alguma meta tag para definir a imagem do site? Para quando por exemplo eu for compartilhar o site em uma rede social, seja exibido essa imagem escolhida agregada com o link, exemplo o print abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem notar ao compartilhar esse link ou qualquer outro sempre é exibido uma imagem agregada, dai queria saber como defini essa imagem?

Comment: Cada rede/buscador tem as suas meta-tags, só consultando a documentação da rede. Isso não é um padrão do HTML em si. Basta olhar o source das páginas que tem o recurso desejado e dar uma inspecionada, para ter um ponto de partida.

Comment: @Bacco entendi, eu pensava que fosse possível definir isso de forma mais sucinta e padronizada!

Comment: Tem algumas postagens no site sobre redes especificas, acho, mas compensa você pesquisar o OpenGraph do facebook, e as meta tags do Google pra começar (que são até reaproveitadas por coisas de terceiros). Tem também os "links relacionados" na margem da pergunta

Comment: Acho que isso se trata do Open Graph Protocol. Você pode dar uma conferida [aqui](https://metatags.io/). Trata-se do og:image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Open Graph Protocol

Como já dito nos comentários, o mecanismo vai depender mais de quem usa do que isso ser um padrão no HTML. Mas existem alguns padrões utilizados pela web. Nos meus sites, por exemplo, eu costumo utilizar o [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/) para fazer isso.

Nele, você basicamente utiliza o `property` para definir o atributo desejado e `content` para definir o valor. Cada `property` no Open Graph protocol costuma vir prefixado por `og:`.

Por exemplo, você pode utilizar o código abaixo para testar isso:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Wallace Maxters" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Um blog com dicas, tutoriais e informações sobre programação">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://exemplo.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://exemplo.com/assets/img/bg.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Algumas redes sociais e alguns serviços, como WhatsApp, Telegram e Slack, costumam utilizar essas informações para montar a prévia do conteúdo.

Se quiser testar isso enquanto desenvolve seu site, você pode utilizar a extensão [Open Graph Preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehaigphokkgebnmdiicabhjhddkaekgh) para te ajudar nessa tarefa.

Exemplo:

[image: Open Graph Preview]

### Sobre a imagem

Respondendo especificamente sua pergunta sobre a imagem a ser exibida, você deve utilizar o `property` chamado de `og:image`. Ele define qual imagem deve ser usada como prévia do conteúdo. Observe que tem que ser colocado a url completa para funcionar.

## Twitter Cards

O Twitter também utiliza suas próprias metatags para essas informações no seu site.
Você pode dar uma conferida na documentação:

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started

Comment: Muito obrigado Wallace conseguiu ser bem claro e tirou todas a minha dúvida quanto a isso!!!